# Weird behavior specifying date limits with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` object indexed by datetimes which was obtained via `pandas.read_csv`. The frequency of the data is 10 minutes.

I want to select a period, say, from `2014-06-15 00:00:00` until `2014-07-01 00:00:00`. When I say that as in

```
a=df["2014-06-15 00:00:00":"2014-07-01 00:00:00"]
```

the data actually starts at `2014-06-15 00:10:00` and not at `2014-06-15 00:00:00`. If, however, I write

```
a=df["2014-06-15 00:00":"2014-07-01 00:00"]
```

("omitting" the seconds), then I get the expected behaviour, which is the data starting at `2014-06-15 00:00:00`. Am I missing something? I am using pandas version 0.16.0.

**EDIT**

MWE data:

```
a,b,c
2014-06-14 23:10,       3.809,  103.0
2014-06-14 23:20,       2.935,  83.0
2014-06-14 23:30,       1.923,  73.0
2014-06-14 23:40,       2.843,  89.0
2014-06-14 23:50,       1.785,  125.0
2014-06-15 00:00,       2.383,  114.0
2014-06-15 00:10,       3.717,  94.0
2014-06-15 00:20,       5.005,  91.0
2014-06-15 00:30,       3.901,  97.0
2014-06-15 00:40,       3.395,  98.0
2014-06-15 00:50,       1.095,  36.0
2014-06-15 01:00,       2.383,  67.0
2014-06-15 01:10,       2.199,  98.0
2014-06-15 01:20,       3.533,  82.0
2014-06-15 01:30,       1.969,  81.0
2014-06-15 01:40,       2.705,  78.0
2014-06-15 01:50,       3.579,  52.0
2014-06-15 02:00,       2.613,  81.0
2014-06-15 02:10,       3.671,  71.0
2014-06-15 02:20,       4.591,  94.0
2014-06-15 02:30,       4.499,  84.0
2014-06-15 02:40,       2.383,  26.0
2014-06-15 02:50,       1.555,  86.0
2014-06-15 03:00,       2.061,  179.0
2014-06-15 03:10,       1.693,  299.0
2014-06-15 03:20,       2.705,  114.0
2014-06-15 03:30,       1.647,  104.0
2014-06-15 03:40,       3.027,  306.0
```

MWE code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("mwe.csv", index_col=0)
a=df["2014-06-15 00:00:00":]
print a
```

PS.: I just found out that this code does not work under pandas 0.14.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of data and code to reproduce this, also what version pandas are you using?

Comment: your data is in the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`

Comment: Sorry about the typo. It's fixed. Pandas version is also updated (0.16). The data should be at least 15 days on a 10 minute-basis to reproduce that exact example, so it wouldn't be a good idea. I'm trying to reproduce the behavior on a smaller sample to make a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  you parse the csv like this (without specifying the `parse_dates` parameter):

```
df = pd.read_csv("mwe.csv", index_col=0)
```

there is no attempt to parse strings into dates. So the `Index` has dtype `object` and the values in the index are strings.

```
In [45]: df.index
Out[45]: Index([u'2014-06-14 23:10', u'2014-06-14 23:20', u'2014-06-14 23:30', u'2014-06-14 23:40', u'2014-06-14 23:50', u'2014-06-15 00:00', u'2014-06-15 00:10', u'2014-06-15 00:20', u'2014-06-15 00:30', u'2014-06-15 00:40', u'2014-06-15 00:50', u'2014-06-15 01:00', u'2014-06-15 01:10', u'2014-06-15 01:20', u'2014-06-15 01:30', u'2014-06-15 01:40', u'2014-06-15 01:50', u'2014-06-15 02:00', u'2014-06-15 02:10', u'2014-06-15 02:20', u'2014-06-15 02:30', u'2014-06-15 02:40', u'2014-06-15 02:50', u'2014-06-15 03:00', u'2014-06-15 03:10', u'2014-06-15 03:20', u'2014-06-15 03:30', u'2014-06-15 03:40'], dtype='object')
```

The string `"2014-06-15 00:00:00"` fits between `u'2014-06-15 00:00'` and  `u'2014-06-15 00:10'` since [strings are ordered lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and [`u < v` if `u` is a prefix of `v`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths):

```
In [49]: u'2014-06-15 00:00' < u"2014-06-15 00:00:00" < u'2014-06-15 00:10'
Out[49]: True
```

(Internally, the string is converted to unicode before the comparison is made.)

The way to fix this is to parse the date-like strings into actual dates:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mwe.csv", index_col=0)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv("mwe.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
```

Then `df["2014-06-15 00:00:00":]` and `df["2014-06-15 00:00":]` both return the expected result:

```
In [57]: df["2014-06-15 00:00:00":].index[0]
Out[57]: Timestamp('2014-06-15 00:00:00')

In [58]: df["2014-06-15 00:00":].index[0]
Out[58]: Timestamp('2014-06-15 00:00:00')
```

Comment: For some reason the `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)`command didn't work with me though.